# On Sylvester's coin problem for geometric progressions

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Given $a,b\in\Bbb N$ we know from http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/INTEGERS/papers/i33/i33.pdf that the smallest number that cannot be written as a non-negative linear combination of integers with weights $a^ib^j$ can be explicitly given when $i+j$ is fixed and $i,j\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$.

Sylvester gave that $ax+by$ cannot represent exactly $(a-1)(b-1)$ different positive integers.

What would be analog of Sylvesters result for general weighted linear combinations of non-negative numbers with weights $a^ib^j$ where $i+j$ is fixed where $a,b\in\Bbb N$ and $i,j\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$ holds?

Comment: I cannot understand the question. What is the difference between "can be written" and "can be explicitly written"? What is a "non-negative linear combination of integers with weights $a^ib^j$ where $i+j$ is fixed and $i,j\in N∪\{0\}$ can be explicitly given"?

Comment: @seva If $i+j=1$ then we have Sylvester's classic result on Frobenius problem.

Comment: @seva there is no diff.

Comment: I think the question for $i+j=2$ is something like the following: Given positive coprime integers $a$ and $b$, how many positive integers cannot be made using coins with values $a^2$, $ab$ and $b^2$? The link is perhaps to some reference for the largest value that can't be made.

Comment: For $i+j=2$ and $a=2$, both the largest elements and counts of the numbers not expressible as $4x+2by+b^2z$ appear to be polynomials, $(b+1)^2-5$ and $\frac{1}{2}(b+1)^2-2$.

Comment: @Seva very first line says 'Given $a,b\in\Bbb N$' and last line has '$a,b\in\Bbb N$'.

Comment: @znt you have correct interpretation.

Comment: @DouglasZare How did you get your count?

Comment: I got the counts by using Mathematica to compute some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $i+j=2$, and consider a representation with $x,y,z$ whole numbers of $n = xa^2 + yab +zb^2$. Note that we can restrict $x$ and $z$ to be less than $b$ and $a$ respectively, as we can find an alternate representation using a multiple of $ab$ to replace one with larger $x$ or $z$.  Thus the largest number which can't be represented is $(b-1)a^2 + (a-1)b^2 -ab$, which should be contrasted with $a^2b^2 - a^2 - b^2$ just using a nonnegative linear integral combination of $a^2$ and $b^2$ alone.

Now suppose we have $k\geq 2$ and a polynomial $P_k(a,b)$ which represents the largest integer not represented with a nonnegative linear integral combination of the $k+1$ numbers $a^k$ through to $b^k$.  To consider the quantity $P_{k+1}(a,b)$ coming from representations using the $k+2$ numbers $a^{k+1}$ through $b^{k+1}$, note that we can use the last $k+1$ terms to represent $Mb$ for all integers $M$ greater than $P_k(a,b)$.  Also, as before, any representation which has $xa^{k+1}$ as a term can be replaced by one where $x\lt b$.  This leads as before to $P_{k+1}(a,b) = a^{k+1}(b-1) + bP_k(a,b)$.

**EDIT 2016.07.04** 
A remark on the Sylvester number is requested.  For a given $k$, note that any representable $n$ by $xa^k + ya^{k-1}b + \cdots + zb^k$ has such a representation where all the coefficients $y$ through $z$ are at least $0$ and less than $a$, as shown above.  If $x$ is allowed to be negative, then any integer has such a representation with $0 \leq y, \cdots, z \lt a$. In particular, the largest nonrepresentable integer is $N= -a^k + (a-1)(a^{k-1}b + \cdots + b^k)$.  Now pick an integer $m$ greater than 0 which is not representable, and write it as above with a negative value for $x$. Then $N-m$ is representable, just by considering the coefficients.  This leads to a bijection on the interval $[0, P_k(a,b)]$ between representable and non representable integers.  Thus the desired count is  $(1+P_k(a,b))/2$.
 **END EDIT 2016.07.04.**

Gerhard "Induction Is A Time Saver" Paseman, 2016.07.03.

Comment: Gee, I could have used $k=1$ as a base case.  Oh well.  Gerhard "Can Hindsight Come Without Regret?" Paseman, 2016.07.03.

Comment: What does $k$ refer to here? Also I think you solve Frobenius problem here and not Sylvester's problem as requested.

Comment: $k$ is what it says.  It is also the sum of the powers, I.e. $k=i+j$.  I suspect the answer to Sylvester's question is $P_k(a,b)/2$.  You might try an argument similar to above to prove such a result.  Gerhard "Prefers To Suggest Than Direct" Paseman, 2016.07.03.

Comment: "suspect not accountable until proven" Turbo, 07/03/2016.

Comment: For the traditional problem with $a$ and $b$, there is a duality between representable and non representable numbers between 0 and $(a-1)(b-1) - 1=N$.  I think if $c$ is representable, then $N-c$ is not.  I believe the same (or a similar) duality exists for this problem, and that the answer is $(P_k(a,b) + 1)/2$.  Gerhard "Hopes To Inspire Other Work" Paseman, 2016.07.03.

Comment: You can also see that part of your problem has a Wikipedia entry.  It does not state the Sylvester number you seek, but it does correctly state it for the case of two numbers $a$ and $b$.  Perhaps a web search will give you the answer.  Gerhard "Lab Hours Over Library Minutes" Paseman, 2016.07.03.

Comment: the duality is not clear for $k>1$ but I believe Sylvester's analogous estimation for $k>1$ is guessable precisely.

Comment: Paseman's answer can also be found in [Tripathi's paper](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/INTEGERS/papers/i43/i43.Abstract.html).